# Efficient generation of Gaussian processes with $\mathrm{Cov}(X_s, X_t) = t/s$?

Tags: pr.probability, algorithmic-randomness

let $X = (X_i)_{i\in \{1, \dotsc, n\}}$ be a Gaussian vector. If the covariance of $X$ assumes a shape like $$\mathrm{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = f(i-j)$$ for some function $f$, then $X$ is shift-invariant and the generation of $X$ is etremely efficient using the Fast Fourier Transform, since in this case $X$ is just a convolution between a well-chosen filter and a standard Gaussian.

For processes which are not shift-invariant as above, but rather scale-invariant, in that
$$ \mathrm{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = f(i/j) \qquad i<j, $$
is there such an efficient way of generating this process ? Of course, I could just compute $\Gamma$ such that $\Gamma^2 = \Sigma$ (the covariance matrix) and set $X = \Gamma \xi$. That would require matrix-vector multiplications and I suppose that for many types of $f$ above, more efficient methods exist ? Could someone point me towards some methods/references ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why not take the process associated to $\text{Cov} ( Y_i, Y_j ) = g ( i - j )$, where $g(t) = f ( e^t )$ and then observe that $X_i = Y_{\ln i}$ satisfies $\text{Cov} ( X_i, X_j ) = g ( \ln i - \ln j ) = f ( i / j )$?